# CSS faq first div work and next not

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a faq for my website.

Code:

```
<div style='margin: auto; width: 750px;'>
  <a href='#q0' onClick="show2('q1')" class='faqahr'>
    <div class='faqquest'>
      <i class="fa fa-question"></i> Question 1
    </div>
    <div id='q1' style='display: none;' class='faqaw'>
      The answer 1
      <br />1
    </div>
  </a>
  <p />

  <a href='#q1' onClick="show2('q2')" class='faqahr'>
    <div class='faqquest'>
      <i class="fa fa-question"></i> Question 2
    </div>
    <div id='q2' style='display: none;' class='faqaw'>
      The answer 2
      <br />2
    </div>
  </a>
  <p />

  <a href='#q2' onClick="show2('q3')" class='faqahr'>
    <div class='faqquest'>
      <i class="fa fa-question"></i> Question 3
    </div>
    <div id='q3' style='display: none;' class='faqaw'>
      The answer 3
      <br />3
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

And on the first div on pass mouse all detect a div: http://prntscr.com/e5zw9m

But on I pass on question 2 only work if I pass on text and don't on div.

My function:

```
<script>
  function show2(obj) {
    var x = document.getElementById(obj);
    if (x.style.display == 'none') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for help.

Comment: please make question more clear

Comment: I can't really figure out what you want to make, but I reproduced your code and it seems work well http://jsbin.com/hiqazofogi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thanks for help, i do a div "box" http://prntscr.com/e600r6 and i click on box1 " question 1 " and work fine but i click on another boxs and dont do anithing... only work on "text"

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tujunaxomi/edit?html,css,js,output if u hover on all texts on first hover all : http://prntscr.com/e60f42 but if hover question 2 only over "quest 2 " http://prntscr.com/e60f8n understand the problem? thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want it to work just as you want, write the paragraph tag properly instead of just using the closing tag!

```
<div style='margin: auto; width: 750px;'>
<a href='#q0' onClick="show2('q1')" class='faqahr'>
    <div class='faqquest'>
        <i class="fa fa-question"></i> Question 1
    </div>
    <div id='q1' style='display: none;' class='faqaw'>
        The answer 1
        <br />1
    </div>
</a>
<p></p>

<a href='#q1' onClick="show2('q2')" class='faqahr'>
    <div class='faqquest'>
        <i class="fa fa-question"></i> Question 2
    </div>
    <div id='q2' style='display: none;' class='faqaw'>
        The answer 2
        <br />
    </div>
</a>
<p></p>

<a href='#q2' onClick="show2('q3')" class='faqahr'>
    <div class='faqquest'>
        <i class="fa fa-question"></i> Question 3
    </div>
    <div id='q3' style='display: none;' class='faqaw'>
        The answer 3
        <br />3
    </div>
</a>
```

or you can use the break tag

I believe that you can achieve the same behavior in better ways .. [Bootstrap accordion](http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp) will be useful